# Computing the condition number for the matrix A

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&&\cdots&&&&&0\\1&-2&1&0&\cdots&\\0&1&-2&1&0&\cdots&\\&0&1&-2&1&0&\cdots&\\\vdots&&&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots \\&&&\cdots&0&1&-2&1&0\\&&&&\cdots&0&1&-2&1\\0&&&&&\cdots&&0&1\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}u_0\\u_1\\u_2\\u_3\\\vdots\\u_{N-2}\\u_{N-1}\\u_N\\\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0\\d^2f_1\\d^2f_2\\d^2f_3\\\vdots\\d^2f_{N-2}\\d^2f_{N-1}\\0\\\end{pmatrix} $$

How do I compute the condition number for the matrix $A_1$ from the equation below for several values of N between 5 and 50?

Any help whatsoever will be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: start with $n = 3$ and $n=4.$ Also, I have no idea what the business with $U$ and $F$ is for.

Comment: You have a nearly circulant matrix.  The eigenvalues of a circulant matrix are given, for instance here: http://web.mit.edu/16.90/BackUp/www/pdfs/Chapter14.pdf